# Why do need both and interpreter and compiler if these are serve for the same purpose?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, v8, interpreter

Yes, I understand the differences, there is no need for explanation.
But what really interests me - I haven't found an answer on these :

1)is interpreter takes the COMPILED CODE or just human written JS code? If compiler process work is set to be before interpreter, I am interested if its interpreting from JS to BYTECODE and then to machine code (and if its like that - `why do we need compiler and interpreter if the final result of each one is the same ???`), OR if it takes already compiled from JS code.

2)can compiler just js code, then compile it machine code, and there would be no need to take interpreter in action? so the action is: can the code be executed only by the work of compiler, without an interpreter?

3)does all of the browsers/computers are using both compiler and interpreter to process JS code? or in some cases code can be just compiled or just get interpreted.

Comment: This is a distinction without a meaningful difference, especially nowadays, when the terms have a lot of overlap.  Compilers and interpreters **do exactly the same job,** though historically they've taken somewhat different approaches.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but why we need both of these?

Comment: Generally speaking, we don't.  We still tend to use both terms, but for the most part they refer to the same thing.

Comment: Your question would be a better one if it were more specific.  Did you have a particular scenario in mind?

Comment: alright, if asking separately, question by question: is interpreter takes the COMPILED CODE or just human written JS code ?

Comment: The word "Interpreter" doesn't make that distinction.  An interpreter takes an input and produces transformed output.  It doesn't care what the input is, so long as there is a specification for it and the desired output.

Comment: does all of the browsers/computers are using both compiler and interpreter to process JS code? or in some cases code can be just compiled or just get interpreted.

Comment: I think you're sort of missing the point.  It doesn't really matter whether you're using the term "compiler" or "interpreter;" it's more or less the same soup.  Nothing about the finer points of these word definitions will help you write better code.

Comment: I understand that. But I am trying to get a better understanding of "under-the-hood" code processing.

Comment: Then ask about that, and not about what the terms "compiler" and "interpreter" mean, because there's no meaningful distinction between these two terms that will illuminate your further understanding.

Comment: My question is not about the terms. Compiler and interpreter are not the same programs, work flows of these are different from each other. And I want to know if the one is depending on the result of the other, or  if these are working apart from each other and actually dont know about each other

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I disagree that there's no meaningful distinction. The main difference is that an interpreter *runs* code, while a compiler *produces* (runnable) code.

Comment: @Bergi: How does that distinction inform the way you write code, or affect your decisions if you're writing an interpreter/compiler?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It doesn't make any difference for writing JS code. But if you're writing a compiler, you need to decide on an output code format; while when writing an interpreter you need to actually interpret the code (which might be done by compiling it to a different format and having some existing machine (e.g. cpu) interpret that).

Answer (score 3):

(V8 developer here.)

A JavaScript engine doesn't need both an interpreter and a compiler. There are JS engines that interpret all code, and others that compile all code.

The reason many advanced JS engines (including V8, Spidermonkey, JavaScriptCore, ...) have both an interpreter and one or more compilers is that the performance characteristics are different:

- Interpreters go to work more quickly, because they do less work up front, but they don't reach very high peak performance.
- Compilers take some time to generate machine code, but once that's done, executing that code is faster than an interpreter would be.

For designing interpreters, there are a few different approaches: an interpreter could directly interpret the parsed JavaScript source; or it could transform it into "bytecode" first. (V8's interpreter does the latter.)

For designing compilers, there's a large degree of freedom/tradeoffs: it could spend more time doing more optimizations resulting in faster code, or it could spend less time producing code but the code won't be as fast. This is why many JS engines have more than one compiler.

So JS engines typically have some sort of tier-up strategy, roughly: the first time a function is called, it's executed by the interpreter. If it runs  long/often enough, it'll be compiled by a quick non-optimizing compiler. If it runs even longer ("hotter"), it'll be compiled by an optimizing compiler.

But if you wanted to implement a very simple JS engine, you may well choose to use an interpreter for everything. Or a compiler.

For further reading, see e.g.:
https://v8.dev/blog/ignition-interpreter
https://v8.dev/blog/turbofan-jit

> This is a distinction without a meaningful difference, especially nowadays

Well, one meaningful difference is: compilers generate machine code at runtime, interpreters don't.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) says that "an interpreter is a program that repeatedly reads instructions (one at a time) and translates them to machine code." And that would be at runtime.

Comment: @MikeM Looks like Wikipedia was wrong there (since July). I've reverted that edit.

Comment: "*There are JS engines that compile all code.*" - one might argue that those still need to include an interpreter, to support `eval`.

Comment: @Bergi: `eval` can be supported by compiling the string that's passed to it. V8 used to not have an interpreter, and it did support `eval` back then :-)

Comment: @jmrk But after compiling it, you still need to *execute* the resulting object code. That makes it an interpreter :-)

Comment: @Bergi: at that point it boils down to your definition of terms. If you say "an interpreter is something that takes JS code and executes it (no matter how)", then "engine" and "interpreter" are synonyms, and "compile to machine code internally" is just one particular way to implement that. From an engine implementer's point of view, however, there's a big difference between "compile to machine code, then execute that code" and "execute without compiling to machine code", and I use the term "interpreter" for the latter, specifically to distinguish it from the former.